# Adaptive Adam-Bashforth method

Tags: integration, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation

Let's say we have 3 time points that are not equally spaced: $t_{i-1}, t_i$ and $t_{i+1}$. Here,

$t_i - t_{i-1} = h_{prev}, \space \space t_{i+1} - t_i = h$

I need to derive an Adam-Bashforth scheme, with a basic integral relation:

$y(t_{i+1}) = y(t_i) + \int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}f(t,y)dt$

Note that $f(t,y)$ is simply a linear interpolant based on $t_{i-1}$ and $t_i$.

OK, so I know that whatever I come up with needs to look like the following:

$y_{{i+1}} = y_{{i}} + \alpha f_i + \beta f_{i-1}$

and I understand that the constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ should depend on $h_{prev}$ and $h$. So this question is basically asking me to find these constants.

Normally, what I would do is set up the interpolant for each constant and then integrate from -1 to 1. So to solve for $\alpha$ using the lagrange interpolant, for example:

$L_i = \frac{(t-t_{i-1})}{(t_i-t_{i-1})}$

$L_i(t_i + hs) = \frac{(t_i + hs - (t_i - h))}{h_{prev}}$

Did I set up the interpolant right for $\alpha$? Because if I integrate this with respect to $s$ from -1 to 1 I find $\alpha = 2h/h_{prev}$. Does that seem right? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: You might have missed $h$ somewhere in $y_{i+1} = y_i + \alpha f_i + \beta f_{i-1}$

Comment: Actually that equation is given but you're right in that normally I would see an $h$, which is partially why I'm confused.

Comment: Why are you integrating from $s = -1$ to $s = 1$? It should be from $s = 0$ to $s = 1$. You are advancing from $t = t_{i}$ (corresponds to $s = 0$) to $t = t_{i+1}$ (corresponds to $s = 1$)

Comment: Holy crap terrible oversight!!!!!

Comment: Sorry uranix, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're interpolating function $f(t, y(t))$ and the interpolant is
$$
P(t) = f_i \frac{t - t_{i-1}}{t_i - t_{i-1}} + f_{i-1} \frac{t_i - t}{t_i - t_{i-1}} = \frac{(t - t_{i-1})f_i + (t_i - t)f_{i-1}}{h_{prev}}.
$$
Integrating yields
$$
\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} P(t) dt = \frac{h(h+2h_{prev})f_i  - h^2f_{i-1}}{2h_{prev}}.
$$
Hence, the method becomes
$$
y_{i+1} = y_i + \frac{h(h+2h_{prev})}{2h_{prev}} f_i - \frac{h^2}{2h_{prev}} f_i
$$
or, equivalently
$$
\frac{y_{i+1} - y_i}{h} = \frac{h+2h_{prev}}{2h_{prev}} f_i - \frac{h}{2h_{prev}} f_{i-1}.
$$
This is perfectly consistent with $h = h_{prev}$ case:
$$
\frac{y_{i+1} - y_i}{h} = \frac{3}{2} f_i - \frac{1}{2} f_{i-1}.
$$

Comment: In your $h=h_{prev}$ case, how did you get a $1/2$ in front of $f_{i-1}$ ?

Comment: @JohnAlberto Thanks for pointing that, i've missed $2$ in the denominator

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! It seems to be much simpler than I thought.

Comment: Not a big deal, but I think after the integration step the last term should be $f_{i-1}$, not $f_{i}$. Also what did you plug in for $t$ during the integration? Just wondering how you chose to actually integrate...